# Do we need the axiom of choice to prove L'Hopital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, alternative-proof, axiom-of-choice

I was looking over an honors-calculus proof of L'Hopital's rule today, and I couldn't help but feel a sense of unease. The proof states that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous on $[a,b]$; differentiable on $(a,b)$; $\lim_{x\to a^+} \tfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$ exists; and that $\lim_{x\to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a^+} g(x) = 0$. WLOG, we may assume that $f(a)=g(a)=0$.

It then proceeds by saying that for any given $x\in(a,b)$, $\;f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,x]$ and differentiable on $(a,x)$. Therefore by the [Cauchy mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem) there must exist a number $\alpha_x\in(a,x)$ for which

$$
 \frac{f'(\alpha_x)}{g'(\alpha_x)} = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)} = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.
$$

From here we can define a function $\alpha:(a,b)\to(a,b)$ given by $x\mapsto\alpha_x$. Hence, $a<\alpha(x)<x$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, and $\lim_{x\to a^+}\alpha(x) = a$. From here L'Hopital's follows since

$$
\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f'(\alpha(x))}{g'(\alpha(x))} = L.
$$

---

The only issue I have with this proof is the idea of choice involved with this function $\alpha(x)$. The Cauchy mean value theorem (which comes from Rolle's theorem, which in turn comes from the extreme value theorem) is not a constructive proof. It only implies that such an $\alpha_x\in(a,x)$ exists; and says nothing to the effect of how one would find such a value, considering there might be more than one such number in $(a,x)$ that satisfies the condition. So in this way, are we forced to appeal to the (full?) **Axiom of Choice**, to properly define our function, and thus to prove L'Hopital's rule? Is there any proof that gets around this issue?

Comment: We need the axiom of choice for performing many usual mathematical constructions (like the algebraic closure, for instance), so that won't be a real wonder. Here we just need that some $\alpha\in(a,x)$ fulfills a particular identity, and any choice is equally good. If $\frac{f'}{g'}$ is continuous, we may pick the $\alpha$ that is closer to $\frac{a+x}{2}$.

Comment: "the $\alpha$ that is closer" is ambiguous. What if there are an infinite number of them?

Comment: If both $\frac{f}{g}$ and $\frac{f'}{g'}$ are continuous, no, that is not ambiguous: the inverse image of a closed set through a continuous function is a closed set (or: for a continuous function, a point of accumulation of zeroes is a zero itself). The worst thing that may happen is that there are two possible $\alpha$s, symmetric with respect to $\frac{a+x}{2}$. In such a case, we may pick the leftmost.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an AC free way of stating it. Let $\epsilon$ be given an $\delta $ be such that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then 
$$|\frac{f^{\prime}(x)}{g^{\prime}(x)}-L|<\epsilon$$

Now assume that $|x-a|<\delta$ then there is $\alpha_x \in (a,x)$ such that 
$$\frac{f^{\prime}(\alpha_x)}{g^{\prime}(\alpha_x)}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

Now we have that $|\alpha_x-a|<|x-a|<\delta$ and thus 
$$|\frac{f^{\prime}(\alpha_x)}{g^{\prime}(\alpha_x)}-L|<\epsilon$$

And so 
$$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|<\epsilon$$

Comment: Oh, of course. You can just prove it directly. I guess the other way is a little more flashy, but this is just as good. Thanks.